# How to attach a jQuery click handler to many IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, for-loop, while-loop

It's not working in the end I want to send the src attribute to via Ajax. I've got 8 buttons with ID's like `#del1 #del2 #del3 #del4`: if you push one of those I want to get the src of the matching id for example: `#del1 -> #med1`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
  for(i=2;i<=10;i++){
    $('#4').on("click", "#del"+i, function(i){  
      var x = document.getElementById("med"+i).getAttribute("src");
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "Delete.php",
        data: { url : x },
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned  
        success: function(response){                    
                alert("esklappt");
        }
     });
  } 
});
```

Comment: your missing some braces, is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching separate click handlers for each `id` is slow and inefficient. It is much better to give all of your click targets the same `class`, and then you can set up the event handler in one operation:

**Code**

NB! click on button **"click 1"** to see the **src** of image **"med1"**.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    alert($("#med" + $(this).prop("id")).prop('src'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="1" value="click 1" class="btn" />
<input type="submit" id="2" value="click 2" class="btn" />
<img id="med1" src="http://www.google.co.za" />
```

Comment: You can pass the alert value via ajax